# How do I play Lucioball?

Tags: overwatch

There are many parts of Lucioball I'm still confused about, in regards to how to play it:

- There are orange hexagons on the field that I'm not sure exactly what they do, since both players and the ball don't spawn there.
- What's the difference between Lucio's punch and Sound barrier? Do they both have the same knockback on the Soccer ball? Or do they both have different knockback?
- What does Lucio's Sound Barrier do in Lucioball? So far I've seen no effect at all; it just seems I activate it and that's it.

Comment: What is Lucioball? I've never heard of that in the context of Overwatch.

Comment: @MageXy https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20216482

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft OMG that's so cool. Can't wait until I get home from work!

Comment: @MageXy It's really amazing. My favorite game mode so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Lucioball, you are trying to get the ball into the opponents goal, while preventing them from scoring on your team's goal. There are two teams of three Lucios each, with a slightly different moveset from a normal Lucio.

Instead of the projectile ability, each Lucio's left click ability is replaced with a punch which is used to hit the ball. Lucio's right click ability functions as normal, and functions as a strong knockback on the ball.

Lucio's Amp It Up also functions as normal, except it only affects the player who uses it, instead of all team members in sight. The biggest change is in Sound Barrier. Instead of providing shields, Sound Barrier pulls the ball towards the player who uses it.

As to the glowing spots on the field, these are jump boost pads. As long as you are standing on one of them (including the ones around the goal) you can jump extremely high.

Comment: I'm trying to find out what the glowing areas do, but I can't actually join any Lucioball games...

Comment: The blog post addresses them: they're jump boost pads: https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20216482

Comment: Just figured that out :D

Comment: The right-click does still knock back enemies